# Python dump json with accents

Tags: python, json, pystache

How can i print a json with special characters as "à" or "ç"?

I can print like this:

```
import json

weird_dict ={"person": "ç", "á": 'à', "ç": 'ã'}
print json.dumps(weird_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

output:

{
    "person": "\u00e7", 
    "\u00e1": "\u00e0", 
    "\u00e7": "\u00e3"
}
```

if i use 'ensure_ascii=False'

```
weird_dict={"person": "ç", "á": 'à', "ç": 'ã'}
print json.dumps(weird_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
output:
{
    "person": "Ã§", 
    "Ã¡": "Ã ", 
    "Ã§": "Ã£"
}
```

How to overcome special characters issue using json? I need to render when i use pystache and try to  print pystache.render('Hi {{person}}!', weird_dict) it occurs me:

```
"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4770: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Comment: Which version of Python? Are those Unicode strings?

Comment: `weird_json` isn't JSON, it's a Python dict.

Comment: @Joe: the output *is* JSON.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry. I claim mid-afternoon blindness.

Comment: @Joe: sure; I think the OP just tried to make a point about the output.

Comment: What happen if you use unicode literal? `weird_dict = {u"person": u"ç", u"á": u'à', u"ç": u'ã'}`

Comment: I dont agree that this question were already answered. i try to run  the solution of @MartijnPieters marked question and it doesn't work.json_string = json.dumps(u"ברי צקלה", ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

print json.loads(json_string)   Output: "×‘×¨×™ ×¦×§×œ×”"

Comment: @ePascoal: The answer there assumes Python 2; drop the `encode` call. If you are using Python 2 there, you are using the wrong console encoding so your unicode literal bytes are misinterpreted. This is not a fault with Python but with your terminal encoding.

Comment: @ePascoal: In my Mac terminal, which is correctly configured, the code you gave works just fine, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, i'm using Python 2.7 in windows. How can i overcome that console encoding? Do you have any suggestion how to modify my terminal encoding?

Comment: @ePascoal: see [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419)

Answer (score 38):

Specify `ensure_ascii=False` argument:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> d = {"person": "ç", "á": 'à', "ç": 'ã'}
>>> print json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
{
    "person": "ç",
    "á": "à",
    "ç": "ã"
}
```

According to [`json` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage):

> **If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
>   output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str
>   instance consisting of ASCII characters only.** If ensure_ascii is
>   False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This
>   usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the
>   encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands
>   unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.