# how to return json with accents and special characters with flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a Web Api with flask, when call my services and i see the results in the browser, the answer never print  special characters

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
```

...

```
response = jsonify({"response": "a á, e é" })
response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
return response
```

The response have the headers, but don't print the accents

Example response for {"response": "a á, e é" }

```
{   "response": "a \u00e1, e \u00e9" }
```

I am currently using python 3.7.4, Flask 1.1.1

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: python 3.7.4, Flask 1.1.1, i´ve edited the question

Comment: That's just the unicode representation for those characters, nothing odd or wrong about it. Try it in your browser console: `console.log("\u00e9");` and it will print correctly.

Comment: I think this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894039/python-dump-json-with-accents